# One Array separation based on second array index value in python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

**I have following torque and speed arrays in python. My question is how can I get corresponding torque values for given speed (Each Torque index is correspond to each speed index). For ex, Speed 1 will have Torque 10, 30, 50 and Speed 7 will have Torque 20 so on.**

---

Torque = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

Speed  = [1, 7, 1, 8, 1]

---

**I tried using Tuple with following code and output, but I cant able to separate Torques for given speed. For ex, at 1 speed *Trq = [10, 30, 50]*. Help is most appreciated.**

---

```
Trq_Speed = list(zip(Speed, Torque))
Trq_Speed.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
print(Trq_Speed)
```

---

[(10, 1), (30, 1), (50, 1), (20, 7), (40, 8)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `enumerate` and a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
Torque = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
Speed = [1, 7, 1, 8, 1]
for i, e in enumerate(Speed):
    d[e].append(Torque[i])
d
```

returns:

```
defaultdict(list, {1: [10, 30, 50], 7: [20], 8: [40]})
```

Comment: Thank you thaavik, your solution is easy and works. Appreciate your help.